# Recompiling output of Erlang's beam_disasm.file

Tags: erlang, elixir, beam

I'm trying to modify a beam file such that local function calls are interpreted as external module calls even though a function may be defined in the same module where it is being called.

Given m as a module, I've tried several permutations of recompiling a disassembled beam file to no avail. Here is an example, in elixir, of one of my attempts:

> IO.inspect(:file.write_file("/tmp/disasm.asm", :io_lib.fwrite("~p.\n", 
>   [:beam_disasm.file(:code.which m)])))
>
> IO.inspect(:compile.noenv_file("/tmp/disasm.asm", [:from_asm]))

I'd really appreciate any input on how I could easily recompile the output of `:beam_disasm.file` back into a `.beam` file.

Thanks!

EDIT: Proving more information

Assume I have an elixir module that looks like this:

```
defmodule MyApp.IndirectMod do

  def value do
    1
  end

  def indirect_value do
    value()
  end

  def indirect_value_2 do
    MyApp.IndirectMod.value()
  end

end
```

After the application is compiled, `:beam.disasm` provides the following output of its beam file:

```
[   {:attribute, 1, :file, {'lib/temp.ex', 1}},   {:attribute, 1, :module, MyApp.IndirectMod},   {:attribute, 1, :compile, :no_auto_import},   {:attribute, 1, :export,    [__info__: 1, indirect_value: 0, indirect_value_2: 0, value: 0]},   {:attribute, 1, :spec,    {{:__info__, 1},
    [
      {:type, 1, :fun,
       [
         {:type, 1, :product,
          [
            {:type, 1, :union,
             [
               {:atom, 1, :attributes},
               {:atom, 1, :compile},
               {:atom, 1, :functions},
               {:atom, 1, :macros},
               {:atom, 1, :md5},
               {:atom, 1, :module},
               {:atom, 1, :deprecated}
             ]}
          ]},
         {:type, 1, :any, []}
       ]}
    ]}},   {:function, 0, :__info__, 1,    [
     {:clause, 0, [{:atom, 0, :module}], [], [{:atom, 0, MyApp.IndirectMod}]},
     {:clause, 0, [{:atom, 0, :functions}], [],
      [
        {:cons, 0, {:tuple, 0, [{:atom, 0, :indirect_value}, {:integer, 0, 0}]},
         {:cons, 0,
          {:tuple, 0, [{:atom, 0, :indirect_value_2}, {:integer, 0, 0}]},
          {:cons, 0, {:tuple, 0, [{:atom, 0, :value}, {:integer, 0, 0}]},
           {nil, 0}}}}
      ]},
     {:clause, 0, [{:atom, 0, :macros}], [], [nil: 0]},
     {:clause, 0, [{:atom, 0, :attributes}], [],
      [
        {:call, 0,
         {:remote, 0, {:atom, 0, :erlang}, {:atom, 0, :get_module_info}},
         [{:atom, 0, MyApp.IndirectMod}, {:atom, 0, :attributes}]}
      ]},
     {:clause, 0, [{:atom, 0, :compile}], [],
      [
        {:call, 0,
         {:remote, 0, {:atom, 0, :erlang}, {:atom, 0, :get_module_info}},
         [{:atom, 0, MyApp.IndirectMod}, {:atom, 0, :compile}]}
      ]},
     {:clause, 0, [{:atom, 0, :md5}], [],
      [
        {:call, 0,
         {:remote, 0, {:atom, 0, :erlang}, {:atom, 0, :get_module_info}},
         [{:atom, 0, MyApp.IndirectMod}, {:atom, 0, :md5}]}
      ]},
     {:clause, 0, [{:atom, 0, :deprecated}], [], [nil: 0]}    ]},   {:function, 7, :indirect_value, 0,    [{:clause, 7, [], [], [{:call, 8, {:atom, 8, :value}, []}]}]},   {:function, 11, :indirect_value_2, 0,    [
     {:clause, 11, [], [],
      [
        {:call, 12,
         {:remote, 12, {:atom, 0, MyApp.IndirectMod}, {:atom, 12, :value}}, []}
      ]}    ]},   {:function, 3, :value, 0, [{:clause, 3, [], [], [{:integer, 0, 1}]}]} ]
```

The particular piece of information to which I'd like to bring to your attention is this:

```
{:function, 7, :indirect_value, 0,
 [{:clause, 7, [], [], [{:call, 8, {:atom, 8, :value}, []}]}]},
{:function, 11, :indirect_value_2, 0,
 [
   {:clause, 11, [], [],
    [
      {:call, 12,
       {:remote, 12, {:atom, 0, MyApp.IndirectMod}, {:atom, 12, :value}}, []}
    ]}
 ]},
```

`indirect_value2` is a "remote" call while `indirect_value` is a "local" call. What I'm trying to achieve is to have `indirect_value` be mimicked/seen as a remote call like indirect_value_2.

I'm trying to achieve this during the compilation process. The only approach I've thought is is to dissassemble the beam file, alter it appropriately and reassemble it. I'm very much open to alternative suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling via `erlc -S xxx.erl` will produce `xxx.S` which when you modify can be compiled with `erlc xxx.S` into BEAM file. But you did not specify what is the use case, where input comes from and where the output goes? Is it OK to use parse transform? Is it OK to use command line compiler or must be called from code?

Is it necessary to compile from code? If so, then someone more familiar with `compiler` module will suggest correct call for your case.

Or maybe for your case it would be perfectly fine to use a parse transformation, where you replace all local calls with `?MODULE:call()` which then will transparently be compiled without any intrusion into what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've provided some more details so perhaps what I'm trying to achieve will be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is Elixir compile-time processing. I am not familiar with how it works in Elixir, but they rely on macros more, and preprocessing before compilation is deprecated/not available like in Erlang or hard to get. If this was Erlang there are tools for what you want. Dig Elixir chat on Slack.

Comment: I've tried the elixir chat, a few elixir people on twitter, emailed the erlang mailing list, reached out to Francesco Cesarini directly, and have now posted my question on stackoverflow.

`If this was Erlang there are tools for what you want` - Isn't everything in erlang also available in elixir?

Let's pretend this was a purely erlang problem, do you have suggestions on how I would recompile the output of `:beam_disasm.file(:code.which m)`?

Answer (score 0):

Again, Erlang compiler is able to compile intermediate results of compilation process. You're thinking to modify beam assembly which in Erlang you can also produce with `to_asm` flag or in shell with a `+S` option, it can be sent back to compiler input. I am just not sure how to do this in code, but in shell you just call `erlc file.asm` or whatever is your filename. I.e. it can work in theory, all pieces are there. It just feels a bit wrong to do because beam assembly is a final result of compilation, highly optimised and many things are rewritten or removed.

Please note that beam.disasm file you provided is written with Elixir syntax and the erlc compiler will not read it, maybe elixir compiler could.

Also note that you're deep in low level compiler territory and if the dragon comes to eat you, only a handful of people can actually help you, so find them in Slack or on the Mailing List.

How I would do this in Erlang: I would modify Erlang AST by writing a parse transformation http://www.erlang-factory.com/upload/presentations/521/yrashk_parse_transformations_sf12.pdf also more docs for it from 2010-2013 [Is there a good, complete tutorial on Erlang parse transforms available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416192/is-there-a-good-complete-tutorial-on-erlang-parse-transforms-available)

I cannot imagine a possible use case for this. What are you trying to do?